# Nexus 7 (2013) stutters while playing games

Tags: graphics

My Nexus 7 device runs smoothly, until I try to play games with it. Whenever I try to play games such as Real Racing 3 or Riptide GP 2, it runs somewhat smoothly, but stutters randomly.

I ran some benchmarks for the device and nothing seems to be terribly wrong with my scores...although they seem to be slightly lower than average. (5-10% lower)

I'm guessing that the stutter has something to do with background processes....but there was over 1 GB of ram when I checked. (not playing the game) And I know its not a wifi issue because it stuttered with WiFi off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to clean cache, clean memory using some [task manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.SmartTaskManager). If it doesn't help, the stutters while playing games may be caused by lack of optimization of the games.

Also you can try factory reset.